# Error with buffer-layout and @tensor-hq/tensorswap-sdk v1.4.5

Tags: js

I am using the [@tensor-hq/tensorswap-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensor-hq/tensorswap-sdk) and trying to use one of the functions in there as follow:

```
import { TensorSwapSDK, CurveType, PoolType} from "@tensor-hq/tensorswap-sdk";

const provider = new AnchorProvider(conn, new Wallet(web3.Keypair.generate()));
const swapSdk = new TensorSwapSDK({ provider });

const initiatePool = await swapSdk.initPool({
    owner: keypair.publicKey,
    whitelist: new web3.PublicKey('DJYCoUYGBjugWLjpT9sdMmpXfxiM2PnvvkneRC6xymsC'),
    config: {
        poolType: PoolType.Token,
        curveType: CurveType.Exponential,
        startingPrice: new BN(0.1*web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL),
        delta: new BN(0),
        honorRoyalties: true,
        mmFeeBps: null,
    
    },
    customAuthSeed: undefined,
    isCosigned: false,
    orderType: OrderType.Standard,
    maxTakerSellCount: 1,
})
```

It throw the following error:

```
.../node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1667
    throw new Error('unable to infer src variant');
          ^

Error: unable to infer src variant
    at Union.defaultGetSourceVariant (.../node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1667:11)
    at Union.getSourceVariant (.../node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1579:14)
    at Union.encode (.../node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1710:22)
    at Structure.encode (.../node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1263:26)
    at Structure.encode (.../node_modules/buffer-layout/lib/Layout.js:1263:26)
    at BorshInstructionCoder._encode (.../node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/coder/borsh/instruction.js:91:28)
    at BorshInstructionCoder.encode (.../node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/coder/borsh/instruction.js:76:21)
    at .../node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/index.js:41:100
    at MethodsBuilder.ix [as _ixFn] (.../node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/instruction.js:50:23)
    at MethodsBuilder.instruction (.../node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/dist/cjs/program/namespace/methods.js:145:21)
```

I try to debug and found out this is the VariantLayout but I do not know what to do
[image]

Comment: have you solve it? met the exact problem.